# Is it possible to update a dictionary based on a certain condition in python3?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want update dictionary keys, with different values. I currently have a dictionary like this

`{'Dog': 15, 'Cat': 9, 'Rat': 12}`

I am trying to update the values such that, the key with greatest value takes an integer number 1, then the key with the second greatest value takes an integer number 2 and so on. I am trying to get the output as

`{'Dog': 1, 'Cat': 3, 'Rat': 2}`

Here is my code below:

````
values = [val for k, val in Animals.items()]
keys = [k for k in Animals]


n = len(values)
count = 1
k_index = 0

for i in range(n -1):
    for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
        if values[j] > values[j+1]:
            key = keys[k_index]
            key2 = keys[k_index + 1]
            Animals[key], Animals[key] = count, (count + 1)


print(Animals)```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following idea:

First create and sort the list according to the values in the original `dict`:

```
data = {'Dog': 15, 'Cat': 9, 'Rat': 12}
temp = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
#[('Dog', 15), ('Rat', 12), ('Cat', 9)]
```

Then use that order to create a new `dict`:

```
result = {item[0]: i + 1 for i,item in enumerate(temp)}
#{'Dog': 1, 'Rat': 2, 'Cat': 3}
```